# Python escape dot character after POST

Tags: python, flask

Consider this string

```
'\.\r\n'
```

because it's a regex, I have to escape the dot to '.', and in POST request I receive "\\.". The result is

```
t = '\\.\\r\\n'
```

Python3 unicode_escape this string to

```
In [20]: t.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
Out[20]: '\\.\r\n'
```

Replace string doesn't help

```
In [21]: t.replace('\\\\','\\')
Out[21]: '\\.\\r\\n'
```

ast.literal_eval also doesn't work

```
In [51]: import ast

In [52]: ast.literal_eval(t)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    \.\r\n
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Let's try to add quote to the string:

```
In [65]: ast.literal_eval('"'+t+'"')
Out[65]: '\\.\r\n'
```

eval is evil, but still the same output as literal_eval
So, is there anyway for me to receive the original string? The only I'm thinking of is using print

Comment: What do you mean by "receive the original string"? Where does this string originally come from? Is it supposed to contain literal backslashes? It looks like you may already have the string you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print '\.\r\n', you will see '\\.\r\n'. So I think you have already have the string you want.

```
>>> a = '\.\r\n'
>>> a
'\\.\r\n'
```